# How to create a button that writes the date at the first empty cell of column K

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the physical button already done, but I don't know what to write in the script in order for it to type the date in the first empty cell of column K.
Appreciate the help.

I recorded a macro, but it writes the date in the active cell

```
function Button() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setValue(new Date());
};
```

I expect the output to be the current date and time reflected in the first empty cell of column K.

Comment: is the first empty cell in column K also going to have other stuff already in that row? Or is it one below the rest of your data?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the last row of the sheet

```
function Button() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var last = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
spreadsheet.getRange(last, 11).setValue(new Date());
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If all columns do not contain data it could be different than the sheets lastRow + 1.

```
function Button() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(getColumnHeight(11) + 1, 11).setValue(new Date());
};

function getColumnHeight(col,sh,ss){
  var ss=ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=sh || ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col=col || sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,col,sh.getLastRow(),1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  while(vA[vA.length-1][0].length==0){
    vA.splice(vA.length-1,1);
  }
  return vA.length;
}
```